# property map does not exist on type promise<void>

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

In my angular 6 project am getting **property map does not exist on type promise** error even I included

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Following is my code

```
 submit(): Promise<any> {
        return http.post('api/SubmitEmployee', JSON.stringify(this.formData))
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .toPromise()
            .catch(this.handlePromiseError)
    }

    handlePromiseError(error: Response) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

After some google I found solution like below but that is also not working

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';  

pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()))
```

After including this it shows error **property type does not exist on type promise** 
Following is my custom `post` method

```
post(url: string, content: any, resolve: ResolveFunction = null, reject: RejectFunction = null) {
    this.clearCache();
    const retryFunc = _ => this.post(url, content, resolve, reject);
    return fetch(appSettings.baseApiUri + url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: this.getCustomHeader(),
      body: content
    })
      .then(result => {
        this.handleResponse(url, result, retryFunc, resolve, reject);
      })
      .catch(error =>
        this.debounce(_ => this.handleError(url, error, retryFunc).catch(_ => reject(error)), this.debounceTimeout)
      );
  }
```

Comment: The variant with `pipe` just uses the newer style of operators, see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md. Otherwise if `http.post` returns an Observable it looks fine to me so the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: If you are using HttpClient, you simply do not need to execute `json()` as this is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

use **from** to wrap http.post like from(http.post().then()) which returns an observable so that u can pipe streams